# Get sibling div id generated by PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML code for kind of blog page. Below - code of 1 post and its height cuts by CSS. It will be many posts on blog page. I want to see all content of particular page by clicking "Read More" button.
Div with blog content has dynamic id which gets from database by PHP.

How can I change height of div with class "blog_article" by clicking "Read More" button?

I thought of using JS/Jquery but cannot get id of "blog_article" div.
Or maybe there is some better way to do this?

```
<div class="blog_article_wrapper">  
  <div class="blog_article" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">    
    <!--Some content-->
   </div> 

    <div class="blog_article_read_more">
        <button onclick="blogReadMore()">Read More</button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but cannot get id of "blog_article" div

Why can't you?:

```
<button onclick="blogReadMore(<?php echo $id; ?>)">Read More</button>
```

Or, if it's a string:

```
<button onclick="blogReadMore('<?php echo $id; ?>')">Read More</button>
```

Then `blogReadMore()` has a reference to the `id`:

```
function blogReadMore(id) {
    // use the id to identify the element and modify it however you want
}
```

Conversely, since you tagged jQuery, you can traverse the DOM from the button click to determine the element without needing any `id` at all.  Something like this:

```
$('.blog_article_read_more button').click(function () {
    var article = $(this).closest('.blog_article_wrapper').find('.blog_article');
    // do whatever you like with the article
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a more straight forward way than Azim's answer, but based on the same ideas:

I would still use the `read_more` class, although not actually needed.  I will assume such a class applied to the button.

```
$('.read_more').click(function(){
    var blog_article = $(this).parent().parent().find('.blog_article');
    blog_article.css('height', '100px'); //change height here
});
```

In this case I use [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method in order to get the parent object from the clicked item, rather than relying on `.closest()`.  Two calls to `.parent()` are needed because the `<button>` resides inside a `<div>` and we need the parent *of that div* before we can drill down.

Alternatively:

```
$('.read_more').click(function(){
    var blog_article = $(this).parent().prev();
    blog_article.css('height', '100px'); //change height here
});
```

Because the button's parent `<div>` is the direct sibling of the one we're interested in.  No selectors needed at all!

Answer (score 1):

You have the id right there, you can generate it just fine with `blogReadMore('<?php echo $id; ?>')`. But you don't *need* the id, your button lives inside the thing you need expanded so you can look it up that way, too.

You're using fairly ancient JS event handling techniques so this won't be as clean as modern code should be (which doesn't use `onclick` and other things, but adds the event listening after the DOM has been set up), but you can just pass `onclick="blogReadMore(this)"` so that your `blogReadMore` function knows the element that triggered it. Then you just go through the sequence of `element.parentNode` until you find the element with `element.classList.contains('blog_article')===true` (both of those have equivalent jQuery calls)

Sort of an answer, but the real one would be "this is not a very good way to generate your code. Generate the HTML and then attach the JS event handling afterwards".

Answer (score 1):

Use a class for `read more` button, say `read_more` like `<button class="read_more">Read More</button>`. And use following jquery.

```
$('.read_more').click(function(){
    var blog_article = $(this).closest('.blog_article_wrapper').find('.blog_article');

    blog_article.height(100); //change height here
});
```